# Android disable settings button in keyboard or block settings screen

Tags: android, settings, android-softkeyboard

On my Samsung tablet i want to prevent user change `keyboard settings`, because malicious user from `keyboard settings` can block my tablet (used as kiosk).

I `override dispatchKeyEvent` in `activity`, but it doesn't called when i click settings button.

I also registered a watchdog to be notified on foreground activity, but the device settings doesn't appear in `foreground activity`.

Ideas?

#### SOLVED

This is the solution to get the foreground activity and force close

```
ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0);
if (processInfo != null && processInfo.pkgList != null && processInfo.pkgList.length > 0) {
    mCurrentApp = processInfo.pkgList[0];
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "am force-stop " + mCurrentApp}).waitFor();
}
```

Comment: I had this problem long back. I will revert you solution.

Comment: what was your solution?

Comment: where is placed your solution?? onStop method?